# Create joomla module with parameters

Tags: php, web, joomla, content-management-system, joomla2.5

I'm new to joomla 2.5 and I was looking at joomla tutorials on how we can create modules, but there's nothing about how can we add parameters to it. What I did for now is that I created a module that display a hello world message to my page and now I want to have a parameter in my module with a label your message. This way, the administrator will set the new message and I can return it using the helper.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the xml file i had to add :

```
<config>
        <fields name="params">
                <fieldset name="basic">
                        <field name="message"  type="text" default="https://osis.extranet.marseille-provence.fr/signalement/new" label="Lien de la page" description="Lien de la page à ouvrir." />
                </fieldset>
        </fields>
</config>
```

then in the helper.php file i wrote this in getMessage function of my class:

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$msg = $params->get('message', 'hello world');
return $msg;
```

And that's it, of course don't forget to add $params as parameter of your function.